# Android DatagramSocket send exception with no apps running

Tags: android, security, adb, system, datagram

While having my Nexus6 (stock android 7.0) connected via adb with no apps open i see with logcat (no filters) the following exceptions every second (with GC freed inbetween):

```
05-18 11:42:29.253 26054-26100/? W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
05-18 11:42:29.253 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
05-18 11:42:29.253 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:694)
05-18 11:42:29.253 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at com.connectsdk.discovery.provider.ssdp.SSDPClient.send(SSDPClient.java:90)
05-18 11:42:29.253 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at com.connectsdk.discovery.provider.SSDPDiscoveryProvider$2.run(SSDPDiscoveryProvider.java:215)
05-18 11:42:29.253 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
05-18 11:42:29.253 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
05-18 11:42:29.611 2011-2020/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 35482(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 33MB/49MB, paused 1.213ms total 132.620ms
05-18 11:42:30.282 26054-26100/? W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
05-18 11:42:30.283 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
05-18 11:42:30.283 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:694)
05-18 11:42:30.283 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at com.connectsdk.discovery.provider.ssdp.SSDPClient.send(SSDPClient.java:90)
05-18 11:42:30.283 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at com.connectsdk.discovery.provider.SSDPDiscoveryProvider$2.run(SSDPDiscoveryProvider.java:215)
05-18 11:42:30.283 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
05-18 11:42:30.283 26054-26100/? W/System.err:     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Connection for both WIFI and cellular network are enabled. I have no special messaging apps installed.
I am wondering which app (none is actively open) is trying to send something. Or is the OS to blame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just found out it was the app of a certain tv manufacturer. Why they need to send sth. every second even though the app is closed is beyond me